# Postgres hide active querys

Tags: postgresql

I need to encrypt some columns in the postgresql for privacy reasons. I would like to use the pgcrypt and encrypt the columns with an asymmetric key pair and the passphrase.

Now you can display currently executed queries. There you will see the private key and the passphrase. Is there a way to protect the executed / active queries from view?

Comment: What happens if the key or passphrase contain a quote? Are you implying that you are not using parameters?

Comment: The passphrase does not contain any special characters. 
The encryption of the columns also works wonderfully.

However, you can use pg_stat_activity to view the executed queries. I'm looking for a way to suppress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters, then only the `$1` etc. markers are visible in `pg_stat_activity`.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be hidden from superusers.  They are already hidden from non-self, non-super users.  To hide them from other sessions of the same user, you can revoke execute on function pg_stat_get_activity from public.